# What are the named Icons in Ubuntu?

Tags: icons, notify-send

I see that I can run:

```
 notify-send -u low -i terminal "yo"
```

and

```
 notify-send -u low -i error "yo"
```

But I couldn't find any mentions of the icon names "terminal" and "error" in the man page. How can I find out what are the other possible icon names? What are they?

Comment: @M.Becerra That is very strange because as I said I didn't see any mentions of terminal or error in the manpage of notify-send. Can you please share what you see there with me?!

Comment: @pomsky It helps me have some ideas but it doesn't exactly solve my problem. I don't want the address of the files I was already aware of `usr/share/icons` but I wanted to just write `terminal` for example not the path to it. I tried the name of some of the icons in the subdirectories on that directory without the extension and it worked but I don't know if all of them will work. So I'm not sure if I should accept it or not.